# Creating second-level AppDomain hangs

Tags: c#, .net, mono, appdomain

I have two assemblies with Main methods.

- The first one executes the other.
- The second assembly creates an object in a new AppDomain.
- That object is about to create a file or print something on the screen.

The first assembly (simplified example):

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("server");
        new Task(() => domain.ExecuteAssembly(PathToSecondAssembly)).Start();
        new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(); //wait forever
    }
}
```

The second one:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("name");
        Console.WriteLine ("A");

        domain.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
            typeof(Run).FullName, false, 0, null, 
            new object[0], null, new object[0]);

        Console.WriteLine ("B");
        new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
    }
}

class Run
{
    public Run()
    {
            File.Create("something");
            Console.WriteLine ("C");
    }
}
```

The result varies depending on the program I execute.

If I run the **second** `Main`, I get:

```
A
C
B
```

and the file is created. I treat it as a proof, that the second application works.

When I run the **first** `Main`, I get only:

```
A
```

and the file does not appear. The application does not crash, but it hangs.

I have verified it both on .NET 4 and Mono 2.10.9 and 3.0.3 (~git head).

Why is that? How could I override this problem?

## ==EDIT==

(tested on .NET)

I'm getting more and more confused.

I have a problem with `PathToSecondAssembly`. When the binaries are in the save folder everything seems to be perfectly fine (tested on .NET 4.0, but I assume mono as well).

When I use a relative path or a path to a different directory the results are as follows:

- in Debug in Visual Studio 2010 I get `FileNotFoundException`, **but A is shown**.

Message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'test2, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

The exception comes up on the line in first assembly:

```
new Task(() => domain.ExecuteAssembly(PathToSecondAssembly)).Start();
```

- when ran without debug, only A is printed, but then nothing happens.

So the assembly is found (A is printed), but somehow the exception comes up.

I have truly no idea why. Some kind of permissions issue? How to overcome this situation?

Comment: what happens if you remove File.Create?

Comment: I've checked and no change, the application still hangs. I've added this file, so that I'd be certain to see some effects of application - I didn't know if Console.WriteLine would actually write in such a scenario.

Comment: Unable to reproduce (.NET 4.5). In both scenarios all 3 `WriteLine`s occur.

Comment: Where does the execution stalls while you are debugging?

Comment: @Dhawalk - I can't verify it now, but I'll try tomorrow. I make an edit, because on Mono the result is a bit different. Damien - as well, I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @Dhawalk - I've managed to check it. Mono debugger hangs on domain.CreateInstance of the second main. And I was wrong, the results are the same as on .NET. Unfortunately, I wont be able to check it on .NET until tomorrow.

Comment: Works fine here using mono 2.11.4 on linux x86-64.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've made an edit to my post with some further investigation on .net 4.0.

Comment: Unable to reproduce as well. Also the whole thing doesn't make much sense. Anyway to solve the second problem (in your update) make use of the AppDomain.CreateDomain overload that takes an AppDomainSetup object. Set this object's ApplicationBase to the folder where the second executable is located.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once (I was not doing the same things, but the failure in creating a 3rd domain from the 2nd domain sprung the memories in my head and then the FileNotFoundException kind of confirmed "my fears").

It's nothing a good'ol Evidence can't fix.
As MSDN states: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.policy.evidence.aspx

***Evidence**
Defines the set of information that constitutes input to security policy decisions. This class cannot be inherited.*

So just do this:

```
class MainClass
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {  
    var currentEvidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("server", securityInfo: currentEvidence);
    new Task(() => domain.ExecuteAssembly(PathToSecondAssembly)).Start();
    new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(); //wait forever
  }
}
```

And if you plan on starting up a 4th domain (and so on), keep on passing the evidence from one "truster" to another "trustee":

```
class MainClass
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var evAgain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("name", securityInfo: evAgain);
    Console.WriteLine ("A");

    domain.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
        typeof(Run).FullName, false, 0, null, 
        new object[0], null, new object[0]);

    Console.WriteLine ("B");
    new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
  }
}
```

Hope that was the issue.